# Create nestjs module without dectorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have an object describing a nestjs module

```
const objectAppModule = {
  imports: [],
  exports: [],
  controllers: [
    MyController
  ],
  providers: [
    provide: 'ControllerDependency',
    useValue: MyDependency
  ]
}
```

I want to pass this to the `NestFactory` to create my Nest application.

The NestJs way of doing this is to create a class `MyAppModule` and to add a decorator.

```
@Module(objectAppModule)
export class ClassAppModule {}
```

Then pass it to the `NestFactory`

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ClassAppModule);
```

I want to achieve the same but without using the `@Module` decorator. The decorator adds some functionality to the class which is missing in my object but I can't quite figure out what is required.

How can I replicate this functionality to do something like this instead?

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(objectAppModule);
```

Comment: I think you just need to add a `module` property that related back to a class (it can be an empty class). You're basically making a "DynamicModule" type match. [I do something similar here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-commander/blob/main/packages/nest-commander/src/command.factory.ts#L31)

Comment: Yes, it works! I previously tried `module: new DummyClass()` but now I see its the reference to the Class and not a class instance. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flesh out @Jay McDoniel's comment, the following worked;

```
export class DummyClass { }

const objectAppModule: DynamicModule = {
  module: DummyClass
  imports: [],
  exports: [],
  controllers: [
    MyController
  ],
  providers: [
    provide: 'ControllerDependency',
    useValue: MyDependency
  ]
}

const app = await NestFactory.create(objectAppModule);
```